# MDX Calculation for fact value through dimension attribute

Tags: sql-server-2019, ssas, mdx

I've got a dimension [D] in my model containing an id [d_id] and an attribute [power].
And I'm having a Meassurement containing an value [prod] which is connected to the dimension over it's id.

Now I want to add a calculated member for [prod] / [power].

How do I do this?
I tried to calculate DIVIDE([Meassures].[prod], [D].[power].CurrentMember.name) which works pretty fine as long the dimension D is in the visible rows.

Is there a way to calculate this even when its shown without the dimension [D] but with other dimensions? So getting the power of the connected dimension for every row in the facts?